# What former rulers of the region were mentioned by Gomez in *The Addams Family* (1965) by Jack Sharkey?

Tags: plot-element

What former rulers of the region were mentioned by Gomez in *The Addams Family* (1965) by Jack Sharkey?

I don't remember whether there was any location given for the Addams Family mansion in the series *The Addams Family* (1964-1966).'

As I remember, Jack Sharkey's book of Addams Family stories, *The Addams Family* (1965) had a chapter where Uncle Fester received a draft notice and caused consternation at his physical examination.  When Gomez hears that Fester has a letter from the government he asks which government.  Gomez says it is hard to keep up with which government rules the area since his government, *Los Conquistadores*.

I am pretty certain I remember Gomez mentioning the Spanish (rather redundantly) and the USA as  later rulers.  I don't remember if Gomez mentioned the English, the French, the Mexicans, the Texans, the CSA, the Dutch, the Swedes, or the Russians as former rulers of the region.

Large parts of the USA were ruled or claimed by both Britain and France at different times, large areas of the USA were ruled or claimed both Britain and Spain at different times, and large areas of the USA were ruled or claimed by both Spain and France at different times.

But I suspect that only a small portion of the USA was claimed by Spain, France, and Britain at different times.

I think that the Spanish and later British claim to Florida included southern Alabama and southern Mississippi.  Thus it might have overlapped with the claim to the Mississippi River drainage basin made by France and later by Britain.

I just checked and there is no claim that Britain ever ruled part of Texas.

> The name "Six Flags Over Texas" refers to the flags of the six nations that have governed Texas: Spain, France, Mexico, the Republic of Texas, the United States of America, and the Confederate States of America.[8]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Flags_Over_Texas

So I suspect that a relatively small region in southern Mississippi and Alabama might have been the only part of the USA claimed by Britain, France, and Spain.

Added 10-03-2023 There were 16th century French Settlements in South Carolina and Florida, and the Spanish had at least one settlement in South Carolina as well as in Florida.  So I guess the Florida, Georgia, South Carolina region also counts as a region claimed by Spain, France, and Britain.

What former rulers of the region were mentioned by Gomez in *The Addams Family* (1965) by Jack Sharkey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story you mention is called *From Here to Perplexity*, a chapter of *The Addams Family* by Jack Sharkey. A letter arrives for Uncle Fester from the government, and when Morticia asks "Which government?" Gomez replies:

> “That new one,” he said. “You know, the one that took over after my
> government, Los Conquistadores, got skunked.”

Rather than Gomez, it is Morticia who then recalls:

> “Oh, yes, the United States!” said Morticia. “It’s always hard to
> remember who’s in charge around here. **Aztecs, Amerindians, British,
> French**—! It’s certainly a popular place.”

-so no mention of Mexicans, Texans, the CSA, the Dutch, Swedes, or the Russians, but there is the bonus of the Aztecs and Amerindians.